# Escurecer Imagem (Degrade)

Tags: delphi

É possível escurecer uma imagem dentro de um TImage no Delphi ??? Existe algum componente, algo parecido para fazer isso ? O Programa coloca a imagem, e eu preciso escurecer logo após ela estar inserida...

Comment: Poderia adicionar um exemplo de imagem antes e depois?

Comment: Você quer fazer uma animação? Tipo isso aqui? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790393/how-could-i-fade-in-out-a-timage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara você Pode Converter em Bitmap e Percorrer a matriz de pixel pixel a pixel alterando o valor de em RGB Proporcionalmente, Pode Ate existir um componente mas Desconheço e outra que a instalação de muitos componentes não é legal, os projetos podem ser descontinuados e alguns métodos você poderá migrar de versão para versão.

```
    function  TForm1.GrayScale (Imagem : TBitmap) : TBitmap;
    var Gray : TBitmap;
    i, j : Integer;
    Pixel : TColor;
    GrayScale : Integer;
    Red, Green, Blue : Double;
    begin
      Gray        := TBitmap.Create;
      Gray.Height := Imagem.Height;
      Gray.Width  := Imagem.Width;

      for i := 0 to Imagem.Height do
      begin
        for j := 0 to Imagem.Width do
        begin
          Pixel := Imagem.Canvas.Pixels[j,i];

          Red   := GetRValue(Pixel);
          Green := GetGValue(Pixel);
          Blue  := GetBValue(Pixel);

          GrayScale := Trunc((Red * 0.3) + (Green * 0.59) + (Blue * 0.0011));
          Gray.Canvas.Pixels[j,i] := RGB(Byte(GrayScale), Byte(GrayScale),          Byte(GrayScale));
            end;
        end;
           Result := Gray;
        end;
```

Esse código de Exemplo passa para escala de cinza para chegar na tonalidade que você quiser
você pode ir alterando os valores que multiplicam o RGB.

Comment: Oi Conrado. A sua proposta de solução parece bacana, mas seria possível você fornecer um exemplo (idealmente em delphi, mas se não conseguir ao menos em pseudo-código)? Assim a sua resposta fica mais completa e potencialmente mais útil para o OP e para a comunidade.